# Single command to create multiple file formats from single source file with ImageMagick

Tags: image-processing, imagemagick

I'd like to render a single file say 1.jpg to multiple Read/Write formats ImageMagick supports for eg. 1.png, 1.tif, 1.pdf etc. on a Windows machine. Is there a quick command to do that or do I have to run convert each time to render 1.jpg to each new output format I want?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this:

```
convert 1.jpg \
        \( +clone -write 1.gif +delete \) \
        \( +clone -write 1.png +delete \) \
        1.tif
```

Comment: Thanks it works! Minor irritation is it creates two copies of gif and png files, any ideas on fixing that?

Comment: Oh, that's weird. Mine does not do that - I use version 6.8.9. Maybe try and upgrade if you are running an older version.

Comment: Mine is 6.8.9-0 and am running it on Win 7 x64.

Comment: @MarkSetchell: If you use `+write` instead of `-write` then you can save yourself the `+delete`...

Comment: @KurtPfeifle Cool - why do you have `\(` and `\)` around your writes by the way? You could equally do `convert ... +write a.gif +write a.tif +write a.png a.pnm`

Comment: @MarkSetchell: The `\(` and `\)` are there for purely pedagogical/educational reasons  :-)

Answer (score 1):

To make it create only one copy of GIF, PNG and other written files, use this command (asumuing, you want to convert `myinputfile.jpg`):

```
name=myinputfile

convert                     \
    ${name}.jpg             \
   -resize 50%              \ 
   \( +write ${name}.png \) \
   \( +write ${name}.ppm \) \
   \( +write ${name}.tif \) \
   \( +write ${name}.gif \) \
   \( +write ${name}.pdf \) \
   ${name}.pnm
```